# ¿Tienen él/ella la misma conjugación en todos los casos?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, conjugación, género

Me parece, por experiencia, que se tiene la misma conjugación para los pronombres *él* y *ella* para **todos** los verbos en cada tiempo, incluso para los irregulares.

¿Es verdad o solamente es coincidencia en casi todos los casos?

Comment: Si. Es correcto. El/Ella son ambos la "segunda persona del singular" y los verbos se conjugan igual ya que los verbos no dependen del género.

Comment: El género no es una categoría gramatical del verbo conjugado en castellano. Sólo aparece en el participio pasivo variable, que es el que se usa en la [voz pasiva perifrástica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_verbs#%22True%22_passive) (respuesta de @ukemi, ver abajo).

Comment: @DGaleano creo que quieres decir *_tercera_ persona

Comment: @ukemi Si señor. Es "tercera persona" Gracias por la corrección.

Comment: **Sí**. Mira [Why is “Usted” grammatically a third person?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/836/5481):Usted comes from Vuestra Merced [...] Since this was an indirect way of addressing someone, it was inflected in the third person. and also [Why are verbs with Usted conjugated the same way as with El and Ella?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23813/5481) Así que **no es casualidad** que use pronombres y conjugaciones de tercera persona. Es una tercera persona que, como caso especial, se usa para referirse a segunda persona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coinciden en todos los casos *excepto en* la [voz pasiva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voz_pasiva), en la que el participio actúa como un adjetivo (declinando por género y número):

> La ciudad fue destruid**a** / La ciudad ha sido destruid**a**.

> Los pueblos fueron destruid**os** / Los pueblos han sido destruid**os**.